In the 2024 rules, is the Reactive Strike from Polearm Master considered an opportunity attack?
The 2024 Polearm Master feat says:

Reactive Strike. While you’re holding a Quarterstaff, a Spear, or a
weapon that has the Heavy and Reach properties, you can take a
Reaction to make one melee attack against a creature that enters the
reach you have with that weapon.

Is this considered an opportunity attack for purposes of the Sentinel feat's Halt ability, or abilities such as a Cavalier's Hold the Line?

This question is similar to: Does forced movement trigger Polearm Master's Reactive Strike?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please use the correct term for the edition.  You used the correct tag  but used "attack of opportunity" in the text. (I edited that).

Although the question that @Tarod helpfully linked to does contain the answer to this question (not in the answer, but as a comment in the question itself), the link is definitely relevant and useful. But the two questions are sufficiently different that I do not consider it a duplicate. Also, the relevant statement in the linked question is stated without evidence or support (though I believe it is correct), so this question gives a valuable space to answer this issue definitively.

I think this question could be improved by starting why you're uncertain. Do you have any reason to believe it is an opportunity attack? Do you have any reason to believe it's not?

It is not an opportunity attack
Opportunity attacks are defined in the rules glossary on p. 371

OPPORTUNITY ATTACKS
You can make an Opportunity Attack when a creature that you can see leaves your reach using its action, its Bonus Action, its Reaction, or one of its speeds. To make the Opportunity Attack, take a Reaction to make one melee attack with a weapon or an Unarmed Strike against the provoking creature. The attack occurs right before the creature leaves your reach. See also chapter 1(“Combat”).

And chapter 1 likewise says:

Making an Opportunity Attack. You can make an Opportunity Attack when a creature that you can see leaves your reach. To make the attack, take a Reaction to make one melee attack with a weapon
or an Unarmed Strike against that creature. The attack occurs right before it leaves your reach.

In both cases, opportunity attacks are described as an attack that you can make if a creature you can see leaves your reach. To execute it, you use your Reaction.
This in both cases does not say that any attack you can make as a Reaction is an opportunity attack. It says those you make when a creature you see leaves your reach are.
The attack from Reactive Strike is not one that happens if a creature leaves your reach, and Reactive Strike does not say it allows you to make an opportunity attack or that it counts as one. As it does not overrule the general rule, and it does not meet the criteria that are defined there, the attack from Reactive Strike is not an opportunity attack.
This is different than in the 2014 rules. Under those rules, the attack was explicitly stated to provoke an opportunity attack (p. 148, 2014 PHB)

While you are wielding a glaive, halberd, pike, or quarterstaff, other creatures provoke an opportunity attack from you when they enter your reach.

